# Указание размера с использованием сдвига <<

Tags: java

В очередной раз увидел в исходниках внутреннего класса IteratorSpliterator для класса java.util.Spliterators такой код:

```
    static final int BATCH_UNIT = 1 << 10;  // batch array size increment
    static final int MAX_BATCH = 1 << 25;  // max batch array size;
```

Для чего существует практика указывать размер сдвигом?

Answer (score 11):

*Предположу*, что эти константы будут играть роль [битовых флагов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) в установке значений, поэтому инициализировать константы сдвигом более ясно (см. [магическое число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))) и экономно (в плане писанины при больших значениях), чем использовать десятичную запись

```
int flag1  = 1;       // 0x1 - 1    
int flag2  = 1 << 1;  // 0x2 - 2    
int flag3  = 1 << 2;  // 0x4 - 4

...

int flag25 = 1 << 25; // 0x2000000 - 33554432
int flag26 = 1 << 26; // 0x4000000 - 67108864

int flags = flag1 | flag3;

boolean isSetFlag1 = (flags & flag1) == flag1; // true
boolean isSetFlag2 = (flags & flag2) == flag2; // false
boolean isSetFlag3 = (flags & flag3) == flag3; // true
```

В вашем примере, вместо `1 << 25` пришлось бы присвоить `33554432` или `0x2000000`

---

Я далек от мира Java, но *думаю*, что компилятор оптимизирует подобное константное выражение `1 << 25` и при компиляции подставит уже вычисленное значение, так что за производительность можно не беспокоиться.

Answer (score 4):

Цель просто получить число 2 в 10й и 25й степени. Это и быстро, и наглядно. Зачем - сложно сказать, надо разбираться в исходниках, но я так понимаю это нужно для побитовых операций, для оптимизации.

Comment: Только единица всё портит. Так и видится: 1 в 10й и 25й степени. А так то прикольно, остроумно.